# How to write a C macro which converts float* to float_ptr?

Tags: c, macros

Is there a way to write a C macro which converts a pointer type like `float*` into, i.e. `float_ptr`.

The following example demonstrates what I would like to do:

```
#define TOT(x) mydata_##x##_t
#define DECLARE(X) typedef TOT(X) { X* p; };
DECLARE(float)   // same as typedef mydata_float_t { float* p; };
TOT(float) v;    // same as mydata_float_t v;
```

But this code fails for pointer types:

```
DECLARE(float*)  // should be typedef mydata_float_ptr_t { float** p; };
TOT(float*) u;   // should be mydata_float_ptr_t u;
```

How can I change the `TOT` macro to handle the `*` and replace it for example with `_ptr`?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `float*` *is* a valid type name.

Comment: There's no way to do this with standard C macros. I question why you need to?

Comment: @ouah: Added a better example.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Totally right. I want to use it as part of a composed non-pointer typename.

Comment: Use `float`, not `float*`, as the macro argument (assuming you really need to do this at all).

Comment: @KeithThompson: I do not understand? `float` and `float*` should result in different `mydata_` types...

Comment: `#define DECLARE(tag_name, type) ...`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: This would be an option :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you make separate maros for pointer types?

```
#define TOTP(x) mydata_##x##_ptr
#define DECLARE_PTR(X) typedef TOTP(X) { X** p; };
DECLARE_PTR(float)   // same as typedef mydata_float_ptr { float** p; };
TOTP(float) v;    // same as mydata_float_ptr v;
```

Comment: This was my first approach, but it requires additional attention from the user.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Remember that the C preprocessor runs before semantic analysis. That is, the preprocessor is a simple text replacement engine that does not understand anything about the C language. It doesn't know what `*` means or what a pointer is and cannot perform this kind of translation.

If the macro language were more sophisticated you could do some string manipulation and convert the `*` to `_ptr` or something, but the C macro language isn't fancy enough for that to be possible.

Answer (score 2):

About the nearest you can get in plain C would be to set up an exhaustive list of type-to-name mappings with C11 generics. E.g.:

```
#define TOT(x) _Generic((x), float *: mydata_float_ptr_t, default: mydata_##x##_t)
```

*Please* don't do this.

Comment: I do not want to do this :D

Answer (score 0):

The C preprocessor isn't that smart; you'll have to roll your own preprocessing code, especially if you're going to want to handle things like pointers to arrays, pointers to functions, pointers to arrays of pointers to functions returning pointers to something else, etc.

Rant time...

Unless pointer semantics are *meant* to be hidden (that is, the user of the type is *not* expected to dereference the pointer with `*`, `[]` or `->`), then **do not** hide the pointer behind a typedef name, even if you have `ptr` in the name.  It doesn't make the code any easier to read, and you're virtually guaranteed of chasing down at least one syntax error every time someone uses it.

Comment: The semantics are meant to be hidden in the way that the user expects `p` to be a pointer to the type he specifies.